# Creating an auto incrementing loop within a function in python

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, increment

I'm trying to set up a loop that keeps track of a number of ordernums as well as assign a nw ordernum to each new order in increasing value.

Here's the full code:

*This is the fixed code using Klaus D. 's advice

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from itertools import count



class ImprintPlusApp:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.counter = count(1)

        master.title("Imprint Plus Manager")

        self.frame_header = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_header.pack()

        ttk.Label(self.frame_header, text = "Bienvenidos a Imprint Plus Manager")

        self.frame_crearorden = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_crearorden.pack()

        ttk.Label(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Nombre").grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Email").grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 5)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Numero Cel/Tel").grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 5)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Información Adicional").grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 5)

        self.entry_name = ttk.Entry(self.frame_crearorden, width = 24)
        self.entry_email = ttk.Entry(self.frame_crearorden, width = 24)
        self.entry_numtc = ttk.Entry(self.frame_crearorden, width = 24)
        self.entry_addinf = Text(self.frame_crearorden, width = 50, height = 10)

        self.entry_name.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5)
        self.entry_email.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5)
        self.entry_numtc.grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 5)
        self.entry_addinf.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 5)

        ttk.Button(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Submit", command = self.submit).grid(row = 8, column = 1,columnspan = 1, padx = 5)
        ttk.Button(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Clear", command = self.clear).grid(row = 8, columnspan = 1, padx = 5)


    def submit(self):
        result = next(self.counter)
        orderResult = str(result)
        print ("Nombre: {}".format(self.entry_name.get()))
        print ("Email: {}".format(self.entry_email.get()))
        print ("Num Cel/Tel: {}".format(self.entry_numtc.get()))
        print ("Información Adicional: {}".format(self.entry_addinf.get(1.0, "end")))
        self.clear()


        messagebox.showinfo(title = "Orden #"+ orderResult, message = "Orden Guardada")

    def clear(self):
        self.entry_name.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_email.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_numtc.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_addinf.delete(1.0, "end")


def main():

    root = Tk()
    app = ImprintPlusApp(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is the question? Maybe an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) also.

Comment: My question is that how could i make ordencount variable keep track of the num of orders created and assign the proper ordernum to each new order created? This way i can organize the orders by their ordernum in a list.

Comment: You need to attempt to work out the logic yourself and then try to code It. If you have problems with your solution, ask about those problems.  Please read the mcve link I posted above.

Comment: If you fail to create a solution, try to explain at what part exactly you failed. E.g. "I remember for loops from other languages, but how do I do this in python?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.count()` for that. It creates a generator, that just returns one number after the other, when you call it's `next()` method:

```
from itertools import count

counter = count(1)
for row in rows:
    row_id = counter.next()
```

In this example on every iteration through the rows you will get an other value for row_id, starting from the given argument (which was `1`): `1`, `2`, `3`, …

Generators an also be used in `for` loops directly:

```
for number in count(1):
    print(number)
```

This will *fastly* print a list of numbers.

In you class it would be a good idea to create the counter in `__init__()` and call `next()` when needed:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    self.counter = count(1)

    …(more code)…

def submit(self):
    my_id = self.counter.next()

    …(more code)…
```

Comment: This method seems promising as I had not thought of it before. The problem is that when i execute the code I get an error. This error is:
AttributeError: 'itertools.count' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: What did you execute exactly? What was the traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/mariorivera/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Test1/Contents/GUI.py", line 44, in submit
    result = self.counter.next()
AttributeError: 'itertools.count' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: Shouldnt the self.counter = count(1) be inside the next()?
Like so: next(self.counter)

Comment: Yes, the code I gave is for Python 2 You are running Python 3 as I see: So it's `my_id = next(self.counter)`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error even though I used the form you just mentioned.